# what is in intuitive explanation of the histogram equalization invariant feature?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

Ojala et al, proposed the uniformed local binary patterns(LBP) approach to extracting rotation and histogram equalization invariant features.

- what is  histogram equalization invariant feature? i need your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a feature that remains the same after the application of histogram equalization.

Consider the following 3 x 3 image (256 levels) -
\begin{bmatrix}3&1&200\\20&32&55\\45&0&120\end{bmatrix}

The LBP is -
\begin{bmatrix}0&0&1\\0& &1\\1&0&1\end{bmatrix}

---

The histogram-equalized image is -
\begin{bmatrix}69&40&243\\97&125&186\\158&28&215\end{bmatrix}

The LBP of the histogram-equalized image is -
\begin{bmatrix}0&0&1\\0& &1\\1&0&1\end{bmatrix}

Both images have the same LBP, since histogram equalization doesn't change the inequalities between the pixel values.

This is because histogram equalization, by definition, remaps the pixel values using the cumulative distribution function which is ***non-decreasing***, 
i.e., **if x1 < x2, then cdf(x1) ≤ cdf(x2)**.